# Optical spectra beyond electric dipole approximation

Tags: optical-properties

I'm wondering what are the typical examples (experiments) for magnetic dipole transitions and electric quadrupole transitions in crystals?

Answer (score 7):

**Observation of a pure electric quadrupole mechanism for a solid-state electronic transition**

A pure electric quadrupole electronic transition was observed for single crystals of $\ce{Cs2UO3Cl4}$.

In the conclusion, the authors wrote:

> Finally we wish to comment on the possible occurrence of other examples of this mechanism. The relative magnitude of the electric-quadrupole intensity compared to magnetic-dipole intensity will increase with increasing atomic radius and most examples will therefore be found in the lanthanide or actinide series.

1. [R. G. Denning, T. R. Snellgrove, D. R. Woodwark, Observation of a pure electric quadrupole mechanism for a solid-state electronic transition, Mol. Phys. 30, 1819–1828 (1975)](https://doi.org/10.1080/00268977500103311).

Other example in the literature is $\ce{Cs2NaSmCl6}$:

1. [R. W. Schwartz, A. K. Banerjee, Observation of a possible pure electric quadrupole transition in solid Cs2NaSmCl6, Chem. Phys. Lett. 79, 19–21 (1981).](https://doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(81)85279-7)
2. [P. A. Tanner, G. G. Siu, Electric quadrupole allowed transitions of lanthanide ions in octahedral symmetry, Mol. Phys. 75, 233–242 (1992).](https://doi.org/10.1080/00268979200100181)

Answer (score 5):

For magnetic dipole transitions, it seems well-known examples are Eu3+ doped phosphors, for example, [Eu3+:Y2O3](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms1984) and [Eu3+ chelates](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-90-481-9751-4_30). The $^5D_0 \rightarrow  ^7F_1$ transition is magnetic dipole allowed, which is competitive to the $^5D_0 \rightarrow  ^7F_2$ electric dipole transition, as shown in the following figure.

[image: MD transition]

This is a kind of examples that almost resembles atomic nature, although embeded in a crystal environment. Anyway, could be a reference.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and writing a self-answer so that future users may find it helpful! Since this currently looks like a 1-line "link-only" answer, it might help if you could expand a bit and go into a bit more detail. We'd like to maintain some minimum quality standards for answers and leave the rest for comments or additional lines in the question!